# How can I have some snapshots of my program?

Tags: windows, screenshot, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screenshot utilities for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows)

I have made a program and to make its report I need some snapshots.I found out that the printscreen button does not work in this case.What to do?

Comment: -1: What platform?  What kind of program?  What do you mean "printscreen does not work"?

Comment: Are you talking about the source code screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean by "make its report"?

Comment: no,the actual program,while the program executes

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag.

Comment: @oli: Windows,when I run the .exe file and while the program executes the printscreen button on the keyboard doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect the print-screen button to do?

It copies the screen as an image to the clipboard so you can paste it directly into a document.  If you use Alt+PrintScreen, it copies just the selected window, rather than the whole screen.

If your tutor required this, he should have at least told you how to do it!

Further for console mode applications, you can capture window content as plain text by right-clicking the window title bar, then select Edit->Mark, then select the text with the mouse, then press Enter.  The selected text will be placed in teh clipboard as plain text.

Comment: I do not need plane text,I need images of my program output

Comment: Also for the alt+printscreen,it works when you do not run the program but while the execution of the program it does not work

Comment: @fahad: Fine then use PrntScrn or Alt+PrntScrn as described!  The plain text suggestion was for information only, you did not state whether the apllication was GUI or text!  I have no idea what your second comment means.  The Window you are copying does need ot have teh current focus.  It is a standard operating system feature - it just works and alsways has.

Comment: while the execution of the program,the Alt+Printscreen gets a black image not the real image.

Comment: @fahad: Then that is an issue with your application and its rendering method perhaps.